# jq Filter: extracting parent values + unique values of array

Tags: json, jq

Here is a JSON example:

```
[
  {
    "AAA": "111",
    "images": [
      {
        "BBB": "some_value1"
      },
      {
        "BBB": "some_value2"
      },
      {
        "BBB": "some_value3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "AAA": "222",
    "images": [
      {
        "BBB": "some_value4"
      },
      {
        "BBB": "some_value5"
      },
      {
        "BBB": "some_value6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The following filter almost solves the required task:

```
cat EXAMPLE.json | jq -r ".[] | [.AAA, .images[].BBB] | @csv"
```

Still, it only gives the result like this:

```
"111","some_value1","some_value2","some_value3"
"222","some_value4","some_value5","some_value6"
```

The question is: **how** to change my jq filter to receive following result:

```
"111","some_value1"
"111","some_value2"
"111","some_value3"
"222","some_value4"
"222","some_value5"
"222","some_value6"
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$ jq -r '.[] | [.AAA] + (.images[] | [.BBB]) | @csv' EXAMPLE.json
```

Comment: Jeff's answer is entirely correct, but you may find this one to follow a more natural progression from OP's "best attempt" to the final solution: `jq -r '.[] | .images[] as $image | [.AAA, $image.BBB] | @csv'`

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of [fkrents](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6524361/fkrents) initial attempt:

```
.[] | [.AAA, .images[].BBB] | @csv
```

leads to this solution:

```
.[] | .AAA as $a | .images[].BBB | [$a, .] | @csv
```